# Laravel: simple form get request returns 500 error

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have this form that I want to submit which is in the view '`blog`'. Now when I navigate to the view `blog` it says the error message oops something.. and I get an 500 error. I'm not able to find the error..

```
 <form action="{{route('editBlog')}}" id="editForm{{$content->id}}" class="editForm">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$content->id}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="text" value="{{$content->content}}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-dark">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

My web.php route looks like this:

```
Route::get('editBlog/{id}/{text}','BlogController@edit')->name('editBlog');
```

And My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;


class BlogController extends Controller
{

   function edit($id,$text)
    {
        return view('edit', ['id' => $id, 'content' => $text]);
    }
}
```

The view `edit` exists and is in the right directory.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: When I take out the code of the form, the view works fine.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of your error?

Comment: `editBlog` route is not defined in your routes actually, your route is something like this: `editBlog/1/2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because your route is something like this: `editBlog/3/34` and your form action is this: `editBlog` and they are not matched with each other, change your route to sth like this:

```
Route::get('editBlog','BlogController@edit')->name('editBlog');
```

and your edit function like this:

```
function edit(Request $request)
{
    return view('edit', ['id' => $request->id, 'content' => $request->text]);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Just for my own understanding, could I have changed the action to match with my original route aswell? Something like  action=."{{route('edit/../..')}}

Comment: @Dom1337 Yes, if your form values are changing at the client side, you can do that by js at client side but in your case, you can do that by something like this: `action="{{route('editBlog' . '/' . $content->id . '/' . $content->content)}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try doing a dump of the `$text` variable? I think it's just an integer, when you're expecting an object because your calling `$content->id` in the view? Doing this should fix the problem.

```
<?php   
   function edit($id, Text $text)
   {
       return view('edit', ['id' => $id, 'content' => $text]);
   }
```

Assuming your expecting a Text model?

Also you should get an error on the page when that happens. Can you check your .env file? Set your env to local like this:

`APP_ENV=local`